# Eager-load an association but ONLY a single column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, eager-loading

I have a self-referential association like this:

```
class User
  belongs_to :parent_user, class_name: "User"
  has_many :child_users, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :parent_user_id
end
```

When I get a list of users, I would like to be able to eager-load the `child_users` association, but I only need the `id` column from it. I need to be able to do something like this without causing n+1 queries, and *preferably* without having to load all of the other data in this model:

```
users = User.preload(:child_users)
users.map(&:child_user_ids)
```

The above works to limit the query to two queries instead of n+1, but I'm loading a lot of full objects into memory that I would prefer to avoid when I only care about the `id` itself on those child assocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want eager loading which is for loading models. You want to select an aggregate. This isn't something the ActiveRecord query interface handles so you'll need to use SQL strings or Arel and use the correct function for your DB.

For example:

```ruby
# This is for Postgres, use JSON_ARRAYAGG on MySQL
User.left_joins(:child_users)
    .select(
      "users.*",
      'json_agg("child_users_users".id) AS child_ids'
    )
    .group(:id)
```

`child_users_users` is the wonky alias that `.left_joins(:child_users)` creates.

At least on Postgres the driver (the PG gem) will automatically cast the result to a an array but YMMV on the other dbs.

Comment: Yea I think you're right, this looks like it's just about the only way to do it. I'll see if this works for my current problem but the whole manual select and group by concerns me since I'm joining and doing real preloading from a lot of other tables too

Comment: You can avoid grouping by doing a lateral join. Adding just a single column to an arbitrary query is a bit tricky but can be done if you call `arel.projections` on a scope and then add your columns to the array.